# Put some CSS style on single template page - Plugin WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm developing my first WordPress plugin for an internship.

I know how to put style on the admin pages by wp_enqueue_style() and admin_enqueue_scripts. I also know wp_enqueue_scripts.

I created a custom post type to store businesses and a single template page in "templates" folder, called "single-myCPT.php".

The problem is: I don't understand how to call a css file for this single page.

The URL is like : `mywebsite/myCPT/company`

When I use the inspector and I go on "Network", there is no css file detected.

Sorry for my English, I'm a French guy who wants to improve that language :).

Comment: Your english is much better than my french!

Answer (score 0):

You can use wp_enqueue_style() and wp_enqueue_script() on front-end (non-admin) pages as well as admin pages.

Use the [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/) action for the purpose.

```php
function plugin_name_enqueue_frontend_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 
            'plugin_name_frontend', 
            plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'css/frontend.css');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'plugin_name_enqueue_frontend_style' );
```

But, you should probably also include your frontend css on your admin page; you may need it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using the WordPress plugin Boilerplate generator. 
So I have already a "public" folder with "wp_enqueue_style( $this->plugin_name, plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'css/plugin-name-public.css', array(), $this->version, 'all' );"

The problem is, in my opinion, the single page is not interpreted like public content

Comment: It's difficult to troubleshoot without knowing more. I use the boilerplate too, but I can't tell from your question how your template is rendered.  You might want to try a good IDE debugger. PhpStorm offers a 30-day free trial, and it is available for a reasonable cost if you buy it for yourself.